# getMore executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage exceeds internal limit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

*This is not a duplicate question. All other answers say that the solution is to create an index on the sort key. In my case, I do have an index and still face this error*

Given a mongodb collection with documents similar to:

```
{
    '_id': ...,
    'title': ...,
    'price': ...,
    'category_id': ...,
    'last_updated': ...,
    ... other keys
}
```

I have an ascending single field index on `category_id` and a descending single field index on `last_updated`.

The following query crashes:

```
> var c = db.collection_name.find({category_id: "categ_id"}, {_id: 0, price: 1, title: 1}).sort({last_updated: -1}).limit(20000).batchSize(500)
> c.forEach(function(doc) {
... ;
... })
2015-05-13T10:00:46.561+0000 E QUERY    Error: error: {
        "$err" : "getMore executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554596 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes",
        "code" : 17406
}
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at DBQuery.next (src/mongo/shell/query.js:259:15)
    at DBQuery.forEach (src/mongo/shell/query.js:414:20)
    at (shell):1:3 at src/mongo/shell/query.js:259
```

Here's the explanation of the query if that helps:

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "db_name.collection_name",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "category_id" : {
                                "$eq" : "categ_id"
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                        "transformBy" : {
                                "_id" : 0,
                                "price" : 1,
                                "title" : 1
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "SORT",
                                "sortPattern" : {
                                        "last_updated" : -1
                                },
                                "limitAmount" : 500,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "category_id" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "category_id_1",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                "category_id" : [
                                                                        "[\"categ_id\", \"categ_id\"]"
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                                "limitAmount" : 500,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                                        "transformBy" : {
                                                "_id" : 0,
                                                "price" : 1,
                                                "title" : 1
                                        },
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                "filter" : {
                                                        "category_id" : {
                                                                "$eq" : "categ_id"
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "last_updated" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "last_updated_1",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                        "direction" : "backward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                "last_updated" : [
                                                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "host",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.0.2",
                "gitVersion" : "6201872043ecbbc0a4cc169b5482dcf385fc464f"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Interestingly, this error only happens on specific categories and not all. Also, if I remove the `batchSize` option the query does not crash (regardless of the size that I set for the batch).

It's worth noting that the `last_updated` field may not exist in all documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, turns out the clue was in the query explanation in my question. Since `category_id` is being used in the query, the query optimizer chooses to use the `category_id` index and completely ignore the `last_updated` index. My thinking was it would use `category_id` for fetching and `last_updated` for sorting but that doesn't seem to be the way mongodb queries work. In order to fix this, a compound index needs to be created for `category_id` and `last_updated` in that order:

```
db.collection_name.createIndex({category_id: 1, last_updated: -1})
```